# Which counts as water for the material component of the Create or Destroy Water spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

Imagine a scenario: A character doesn't have a spellcasting focus, and his party is going to die because they don't have water.

What else can be used as a component to cast the [*create or destroy water*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-or-destroy-water) spell?

The material component is listed as:

> (**a drop of water if creating water** or a few grains of sand if destroying it)

But what counts as water for the spell? Can it be water from pee? Sweat? Anything else?

As a DM, would you let the player use something else like sweat?

Comment: do you have a cleric in the party that can "purify food and **water**"

Answer (score 4):

#### What counts as "water" is undefined, and therefore up to the DM.

The spell component for *create or destroy water* is "a drop of water". Water isn't strictly defined anywhere in the rules, leaving it up to the standard English definition of the word. The DM has to interpret any remaining ambiguity.

The rules don't say anything about how pure the water has to be. Salt water might count as water, as may dirty water. Saliva is 99.5% water, and probably more pure than some water sources you'd find in a dungeon.

Urine is over 90% water, but many people would consider it not water due to its lack of potability. Blood would probably not be considered water, even though it contains 92% water and is described by Wikipedia as "essentially an aqueous solution", or water with stuff dissolved in it; likewise potions, beer, or other liquids defined by their difference from water.

The exact definition of water is, however, **entirely up to the DM's opinion**. The DM may feel generous or strict depending on the circumstances.

Comment: I'd like to remind you that salt water is also a *aqueous solution*. Making a decision ***against*** the use of a substance based on this term being used to describe it should ***not*** be done.

Comment: This is really a situation where DMs can rule differently and the definition of water is not covered in the rules. I suspect Jeremy Crawford would take the literal approach and rule that that salt water is water and blood is blood, even though scientifically speaking salt water may have less H2O than an equivalent quantity of blood.

Comment: Blood isn't an aqueous solution; it's at least 30% solid particles. Blood also has powerful magical associations of its own, and there are several spells that use it as a component.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on dm tbh 
One who is giving ruling using rule of cool sure they'd probably allow it.

If your going by Rules As Written it calls for water. Not sweat , urine, saliva , or blood.

However using xanathars guide to everything. P79. The brewer supplies potable water feature you might be able to purify urine to be drinkable than use create or destroy water.

I personally would allow it due to me personally loving the avatar the last air bender scene of sweat being used by Korra to break out of a cell.

Even if I would say no to sweat/urine if the party had a brewers tools or a knowledge cleric who used channel divinity for brewers tools I would then allow it.